# How to sort attendance date along with the month?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

Attendance is sorting according to date, that is fine, but I want to **sort date along with the month name** January should come at the bottom, and December at the top.

Table

```
Attendance Date
---------------
26 Feb 2018
19 Dec 2018
18 Dec 2018
14 Dec 2018
12 June 2018
7 Dec 2018
5 Feb 2018
```

Query

```
select distinct 
    (select ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[to_char(t1.l_time,'HH12:mi AM')]::text), ',')
     from
         (select (al1.create_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+5:30')::time as l_time
          from users.access_log as al1
          where al1.user_id = al.user_id
            and al1.login_status = 1
            and al1.create_time::date = al.create_time::date
          order by al1.create_time::time ASC
         ) as t1
    ) as login_time,
    (select ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[to_char(t2.o_time,'HH:mi AM')]::text), ',')
     from
         (select (al2.create_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC+5:30')::time as o_time
          from users.access_log as al2
          where al2.user_id = al.user_id
            and al2.login_status = 0
            and al2.create_time::date = al.create_time::date
          order by al2.create_time::time ASC
         ) as t2
    ) as logout_time,
    al.create_time::date
from users.access_log as al
where al.user_id = ?;
```

Attendance is sorting according to date, that is fine, but I want to **sort date along with the month name** January should come at the bottom, and December at the top.

Comment: k sure bro. form next time i'll

Comment: What data type is the column `Attendance Date`? The query you have shown does not use a column of that name nor does it output have a column of that name. It also seems that the query generates something completely different than the output you have shown (comma separated times, rather than dates)